# Raising an Exception from Objective-C back to Javascript

Tags: ios, exception, javascriptcore

JavascriptCore permits us to expose our Objective-C classes to javascript via the JSExport protocol.  Let's say, in one of the exposed Objective-C class's methods, a condition is encountered where it makes sense to raise an exception.  Is there a way to create said exception and raise it such that the javascript code can process it as it would process a regular javascript exception?

I tried doing a regular old `[NSException raise...]` and that immediately caused a crash.

Am I relegated to detecting the raise condition, passing that condition back to javascript, and having the javascript do the throw?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but the instances in which it makes sense to throw an exception in Objective-C are extraordinarily few and far between.

Comment: True.  In this case, the Objective-C is merely an endpoint for a javascript call.  The intent is for the exception to get thrown to the javascript code and handled there.

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C `JSContext` object have exception property, that may be used to throw an exception to JavaScript. According comments in header file:

> Before a callback is made from JavaScript to an Objective-C block or
>   method,  the prior value of the exception property will be preserved
>   and the property  will be set to nil. After the callback has completed
>   the new value of the  exception property will be read, and prior value
>   restored. If the new value  of exception is not nil, the callback will
>   result in that value being thrown.