# Catch an objectiveC exception that was thrown as a result of a javascript script

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, javascriptcore

Is there any way of catching an Objective-C exception that was thrown as a result of a JavaScript script evaluation?

For example: 
I have a class Obj with a method canThrow that I have exported through JSExport. From some script I call this method and it indeed throws an exception.
Any way I can handle it?

I have already tried to wrap the script evaluation code in a try-catch, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit unclear, but I will try to answer it anyway.

If you need to raise an exception from Objective-C to Javascript, you should use `-[JSContext exception]` property. See [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29979041/1689609) for details.

Passing exception from Javascript to Objective-C is straightforward, you simply export some method, that will handle exception in Objective-C like:

```
myJSContext[@"PassExceptionToObjC"] = ^void(JSValue *)jsException {
    // Handle exception
}
```

And then use following code in Javascript:

```
try {
    // some code
}
catch (exception) {
    PassExceptionToObjC(exception);
}
```

Alternatively you can return specific value from your Javascript to Objective-C. Like:

```
function doSomething() {
    try {
        // Do something
        return 'Ok';
    }
    catch (error) {
        return 'Error happens ' + error.message;
    }
}
```

In case you need to avoid throwing Objective-C exception in method, called from Javascript, you simply should add `@try/@catch` in your Objective-C method or block:

```
myJSContext[@"DoSomething"] = ^void(JSValue *)someValue {
    @try {
        // Do something
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

Or, preferred, change logic of Objective-C code, that trigger exception.

Similar way applies if you need to avoid exception in Javascript, called from Objective-C. You simply add `try/catch`. In most cases you may simply ignore exceptions in JavaScript, called from Objective-C. But I suggest to implement exception handing on Objective-C side for any non-trivial Javascript, at least to simplify troubleshooting.

Hope it helps.